# Passing changing data using html5 file uploader

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

[html 5 file uploader](https://github.com/devbridge/html5-file-uploader)

I am using the module linked above.  I found out that I need to pass some more information to the backend about the file that is being uploaded.  How would I do this without modifying the module.

What I want to pass is a string that changes when a new file is uploaded.  There are a few options to pass in extra data or key, but it is only set when initialized and I need it change when I decide to upload a new file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are other options the html 5 file uploader provides.  Like 'data' for extra data to send with the formdata that sent to the back end.